# $n$-th order derivative of the modulus of a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Assume that $c:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^m$ is a $C^\infty$ function such that $c$ never assumes the value $0\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Then $|c|$ is $C^\infty$ as well.

Is there a nice and concise way to express the $n$-th order derivative of $|c|$?

Comment. That $c$ is $C^\infty$ is well-known and easy to prove without explicitly computing higher-order derivatives. The question is about a closed formula expressing the $n$-th order derivative.

Comment: By $|c|$ do you mean the Euclidean norm in $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: In any case, I don't think you should explicitly compute the $n$th derivative of $|c|$, I think you should show that $|\cdot |$ is $C^\infty$ away from $0$.

Comment: You don't want to write out explicit derivatives. You want to use the chain rule a few times: once to deduce $|x|$ is smooth away from $x=0$, again with $c$ in there. Then you can prove by induction, if you insist, with the chain rule to see that the composition of smooth functions is smooth.

Comment: I do not get your comments. The premise I wrote is well-known and easy to prove without explicitly computing higher-order derivatives. But I was wondering for some closed formula to express the derivative.

Comment: @Kosh Forgive us for thinking this was your attempt to prove the result. I don't know of a nice closed formula for the $n$th derivative of $|c|$.